# Custom Slider Windows 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

i need to create a custom slider, at the moment my slider looks exactly how i want, it looks like this (image from VisualStudio):

[image]
ant the xaml code is this:

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
    <Grid Height="240" Width="300" Canvas.ZIndex="2">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" 
                             Angle="-125" 
                             CenterX="150" 
                             CenterY="150" />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>

        <Ellipse Height="54" Width="54" 
                 x:Name="knob"
                 Fill="Red"
                 PointerMoved="Image_PointerMoved" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Margin="0,-7,0,0"/>
    </Grid>

    <Path x:Name="path"
          Data="M269.01,233.229 C303.532,181.303 304.261,118.855 269.097,67.0139 C207.933,-15.2077 92.8603,-16.8742 31.2108,66.0937 C-3.68835,121.514 -3.36331,179.271 30.8461,232.917 C51.2571,253.282 74.8965,230.573 61.3585,209.167 C38.2919,172.761 36.0008,129.688 62.1396,90.2093 C106.398,28.022 194.916,29.4803 237.509,90.1399 C262.554,127.345 263.613,170.209 237.647,209.792 C227.355,233.49 250.474,250.782 269.01,233.229 z" 
          Stretch="Fill"  
          Fill="Gray" />

</Grid>
```

and the C# code is this:

```
private void Image_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Canculate the current rotation angle and set the value.
        var newPos = e.GetCurrentPoint(path);
        double angle = GetAngleR(newPos.Position);

        rotateTransform.Angle = angle;
    }

    public double GetAngleR(Point pos)
    {
        var xDiff = 150 - pos.X;
        var yDiff = 150 - pos.Y;
        var r = Math.Sqrt((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff));

        var radians = Math.Acos((yDiff) / r);

        var angle = radians * (180 / Math.PI);

        if(angle > 125)
        {
            angle = 125;
        }

        if(pos.X < 150)
        {
            angle = -angle;
        }

        return angle;
    }
```

my problem is how i fill the path with a different color as i move the ellipse?

i need to achive somethig like this:

[image]

any suggestion?

Comment: Oh this look like a neat one! I'd probably look at opacity mask with direct2D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have figured out how to do this slider, this isn't a perfect solution but it works and for me is enough.

I have created a `GeometryGroup`  that contains some `BezierSegment` used to draw the arch path and then I have added a to the group a `RectangleGeometry` that is the size of the element.

With `GeometryGroup` in this case,  the intersecting area of two shapes is not filled.

After that i have placed the right color behind the main path.

this is the code:

**XAML**

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
    <Grid Height="240" Width="300" Canvas.ZIndex="2">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" 
                             Angle="-125" 
                             CenterX="150" 
                             CenterY="150" />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>

        <Image Height="54" Width="54" x:Name="knob"
               Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ic_slider_credito.png" 
               PointerMoved="Image_PointerMoved" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               Margin="0,-5,0,0" />
    </Grid>

    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Fill="Gray" 
               Width="300" 
               Height="240" />

    <Path x:Name="fillPath" 
          Height="240"
          Width="300"
          UseLayoutRounding="False"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Fill="Orange" />

    <Path x:Name="path" 
          Height="240"
          Width="300"
          UseLayoutRounding="False"
          Stretch="Fill"  
          Fill="White" />
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
    public SliderInvioCredito()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DrawPath();
    }

    private void Image_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newPos = e.GetCurrentPoint(path);
        double angle = GetAngleR(newPos.Position);

        rotateTransform.Angle = angle;
    }

    public double GetAngleR(Point pos)
    {
        var xDiff = 150 - pos.X;
        var yDiff = 150 - pos.Y;
        var r = Math.Sqrt((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff));

        var radians = Math.Acos((yDiff) / r);

        var angle = radians * (180 / Math.PI);

        if (angle > 125)
        {
            angle = 125;
        }

        if (pos.X < 150)
        {
            angle = -angle;
        }

        DrawFillPath(pos.X, pos.Y, angle);

        return angle;
    }

    private void DrawFillPath(double x, double y, double angle)
    {
        var start = new Point(150, 120);
        var pth = new PathFigure();
        pth.StartPoint = start;

        var ls1 = new LineSegment();
        ls1.Point = start;
        pth.Segments.Add(ls1);

        var ls8 = new LineSegment();
        ls8.Point = new Point(150, 240);
        pth.Segments.Add(ls8);

        var ls2 = new LineSegment();
        ls2.Point = new Point(0, 240);
        pth.Segments.Add(ls2);

        if (angle > -45)
        {
            var ls5 = new LineSegment();
            ls5.Point = new Point(0, 0);
            pth.Segments.Add(ls5);

            if (angle > -30)
            {
                var ls6 = new LineSegment();
                ls6.Point = new Point(x, 0);
                pth.Segments.Add(ls6);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var ls3 = new LineSegment();
            ls3.Point = new Point(0, y);
            pth.Segments.Add(ls3);
        }

        if (angle > 45)
        {
            var ls7 = new LineSegment();
            ls7.Point = new Point(300, 0);
            pth.Segments.Add(ls7);

            var ls9 = new LineSegment();
            ls9.Point = new Point(300, y);
            pth.Segments.Add(ls9);
        }

        var ls4 = new LineSegment();
        ls4.Point = new Point(x, y);
        pth.Segments.Add(ls4);

        var pthCollection = new PathFigureCollection();
        pthCollection.Add(pth);

        var pthGeometry = new PathGeometry();
        pthGeometry.Figures = pthCollection;

        fillPath.Data = pthGeometry;
    }

    private void DrawPath()
    {
        var cc1 = new BezierSegment();
        cc1.Point1 = new Point(303.532, 181.303);
        cc1.Point2 = new Point(304.261, 118.855);
        cc1.Point3 = new Point(269.097, 67.0139);

        var cc2 = new BezierSegment();
        cc2.Point1 = new Point(207.933, -15.2077);
        cc2.Point2 = new Point(92.8603, -16.8742);
        cc2.Point3 = new Point(31.2108, 66.0937);

        var cc3 = new BezierSegment();
        cc3.Point1 = new Point(-3.68835, 121.514);
        cc3.Point2 = new Point(-3.36331, 179.271);
        cc3.Point3 = new Point(30.8461, 232.917);

        var cc4 = new BezierSegment();
        cc4.Point1 = new Point(51.2571, 253.282);
        cc4.Point2 = new Point(74.8965, 230.573);
        cc4.Point3 = new Point(61.3585, 209.167);

        var cc5 = new BezierSegment();
        cc5.Point1 = new Point(38.2919, 172.761);
        cc5.Point2 = new Point(36.0008, 129.688);
        cc5.Point3 = new Point(62.1396, 90.2093);

        var cc6 = new BezierSegment();
        cc6.Point1 = new Point(106.398, 28.022);
        cc6.Point2 = new Point(194.916, 29.4803);
        cc6.Point3 = new Point(237.509, 90.1399);

        var cc7 = new BezierSegment();
        cc7.Point1 = new Point(262.554, 127.345);
        cc7.Point2 = new Point(263.613, 170.209);
        cc7.Point3 = new Point(237.647, 209.792);

        var cc8 = new BezierSegment();
        cc8.Point1 = new Point(227.355, 233.49);
        cc8.Point2 = new Point(250.474, 250.782);
        cc8.Point3 = new Point(269.01, 233.229);

        var pthFigure = new PathFigure();
        pthFigure.StartPoint = new Point(269.01, 233.229);

        var psc = new PathSegmentCollection();
        psc.Add(cc1);
        psc.Add(cc2);
        psc.Add(cc3);
        psc.Add(cc4);
        psc.Add(cc5);
        psc.Add(cc6);
        psc.Add(cc7);
        psc.Add(cc8);

        pthFigure.Segments = psc;

        var pthFigureCollection = new PathFigureCollection();
        pthFigureCollection.Add(pthFigure);

        var pthGeometry = new PathGeometry();
        pthGeometry.Figures = pthFigureCollection;

        var rect = new RectangleGeometry();
        rect.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 300, 240);

        var gg = new GeometryGroup();
        gg.Children.Add(pthGeometry);
        gg.Children.Add(rect);

        path.Data = gg;
    }
```